# How can i disable my button after i clicked it 10 times and it will say "Countdown Completed" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var count = 10;
function countdown() {
  count--;
  $("#count").text(count);
  console.log(count);
  countComplete();
}

function countComplete() {
  if (count <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="done";
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoting is intended for bad questions/answers, which this is.  It is too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to decrease your counter on every click and if it becomes 0 then change button text and disable it.

```
let clicksLeft = 10;
const $count = $('#count').text(clicksLeft);

$('button').on('click', function() {
  --clicksLeft;
  $count.text(clicksLeft);

  if (!clicksLeft) {
    this.innerText = 'Countdown Completed';
    this.disabled = true;
  }
});
```